# Store Javascript PageMethods "return value" into a variable

Tags: c#, javascript, variable-assignment, pagemethods

I have a sample code as follows:

```
PageMethods.getServerTime(DateTimeFormat, OnRequestComplete, OnError);
```

It uses the Javascript PageMethods to call the C# function `getServerTime`. However, I notice that if I use the following code, I will be able to view the "return value".

```
    function OnRequestComplete(result) {
        alert(result);
    }
```

However, if I tried to use the following code:

```
var result = "";
result = PageMethods.getServerTime(DateTimeFormat, OnRequestComplete, OnError);
```

I will always get nothing.

From my understanding and research through the Internet, it seems that the result conclude the following:

```
Because the ajax call is async. It does not wait for the ajax call to complete.
```

Thus, does it mean that there is no work around in this whole world capable of storing the "result value" to a **Javascript variable**?

I can only put a `alert()` or use a `<div>` to display the result. There is no chance to store it to a Javascript variable for later use?

Answer (score 0):

You're right.  Because the call is asynchronous there is no value to be assigned to "result" at the moment you call getServerTime.  But you have hit the nail on the head by using OnRequestComplete, as that is where you can be sure it has been set.  If you then need to do something with the value, such as display it to the user, then you must do so in this method or by calling another method from within.

```
var result = "";
function OnRequestComplete(res) {
    result = res;
    DoSomethingWithResult();
}

function DoSomethingWithResult(){
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thank for confirming my conclusion. By the way, your code also mean that I have to use the `result` immediately regardless whether in `OnRequestComplete` function or `DoSomethingWithResult` function. If I am outside the functions, I will lose both value. I just want to store it in a simple Javascript variable so that I can use it at a later time.